# Float Power program in c without math.h

Tags: c

Sir, I want to make a power program of float without including math.h  library.
Can you help me?
E.g. 4.2^2.3

Comment: why on earth should one do that?

Comment: Please consider reformulating your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think the question is fine, the answer can be calculated by re-formatting the equation. For example 4.2^2.3 = 4.2^2 * 4.2^1/3 = 4.2*4.2 * cuberoot(4.2). The roots you can calculate using logs or Newton's method.

Comment: @ventsyv This gives an approximation but is not correct since x^0.3 ≠ ³√x.

Comment: @FUZxxl My bad. I was doing quick and dirty solution and it came out wrong. The principal remains though:  4.2^2 * 4.2^0.3 = 4.2*4.2 *  4.2^(3/10) ... etc

Comment: @ventsyv Now you need a function to compute x^3/10 = ¹⁰√x³ which isn't available. You still need to implement logarithms.

Comment: @FUZxxl log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b), as long as you know log 1 - 9 (log(0)=0, log(10) = 1) you can calculate the rest. Maybe you can "cheat" and use a look up table...

Comment: Dear I need to use a series but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

Floating point math is still available without `math.h`—you just don't have access to the functions it provides. You can still do basic operations like `1.0 + 1.0`.

Have a look at how to compute the *exponential* and *logarithmic* functions (to base e) and then compute *x*<sup>*y*</sup> using the identity

> *x*<sup>*y*</sup> = exp(*y* · ln *x*).

Comment: Since `exp()` is also in `math.h`, wouldn't it just be easier to use `pow` directly?

Comment: @Jongware I'm not telling OP to use `exp()`, since he is apparently not allowed to use that. I'm telling him to look up how `exp()` is computed so he can implement it himself.

Comment: @MuhammadKamranJaved Have a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation) and [that page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: @MuhammadKamranJaved When you have implemented the *exponential function* as `my_exp()` and the *logarithmic function* as `my_ln()`, your `my_pow()` function should look like this: `double my_pow(double x, double y) { return my_exp(y * my_ln(x)); }`.